# Probability - drawing balls from an urn w/o replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that an urn contains $8$ red balls and $4$ white balls. We draw $2$ balls from the urn without replacement. If we assume that at each draw each ball in the urn is equally likely to be chosen, what is the probability that both balls are red?

At this point the book denotes two sets: $R_1$={the first ball is red} and $R_2$={the second ball is red}, we know that $$P(R_1)=\frac{|R_1|}{|S|},$$ the sample space is $$\binom{12}{2}=66$$ but the book how it gets $$P(R_1)=\frac{8}{12}\, ?$$

Answer (score 2):

P(R_1) is only the probability that the first ball is red. This is correct, but it does not answer the question of the probability that both are red.

Also R_1 and R_2 are NOT disjoint, because it is possible for BOTH of the events to happen.

Comment: For example if there are 3 red balls and 2 white balls what are the elements of $$R_1$$?

Comment: Well it is hard to describe the sets unless you have some labels. If 1,2,3 are red and 4,5 are white, then elements of R_1 are (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,1), (2,3), etc. ie any pair where the first coordinate corresponds to red.

Answer (score 2):

I will use my method to answer the question first. Assume you draw $2$ balls from the $12$ balls in the urn. The number of possibilities is $^{12}C_2 = 66$. Of which, the number of possibilities where

- both are red are  $^8C_2 = 28$
- 1 red and 1 white are $8\times4=32$
- both are white are $^4C_2 = 6$

Add them up and you get $66$, which is the sample space.

Hence, $$\begin{align*}P(\text{both red}) &= \frac{28}{66}\\\\&=\frac{14}{33}\end{align*}$$

**UPDATED**
Now, my recommendation for your question. You should define the **event**

- $R_1$ is the event that first draw is red
- $R_2$ is the event that second draw is red

$$\begin{align*}P(R_1 \cap R_2) &=  P(R_1)\times P(R_2 | R_1) \\&=\frac{8}{12} \times \frac{7}{11}\\&= \frac{56}{132}\\&=\frac{14}{33}\end{align*}$$

You get the same answer.

Comment: I certainly agree that the second way is good. It would be I think better not to refer to Bayes. And the order $\frac{8}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{11}$ is more intuitive.

Comment: How do you get |R_1| using binomial?

Comment: Hello @AndréNicolas, I have made the recommended changes. Hmm...@blob, i do not understand your question. There is no need to use binomial distribution here. Simply consider conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

The sets where the first ball is red an the one in which the second one is red are not disjoint.

He gets $P(R_1)$ because there are 8 ways to chose the first ball and $11$ to choose the second one so there are 56 ways to chose a red ball first ( $|R_1|=56$) and

$|S|= 132$ THIS WAS WRONG. Order does matter when seeing which one is picked first

$$\frac{|R_1|}{|S|}=\frac{88}{132}=\frac{8}{12}$$

---

> This is not an effective way to solve the problem however. This is how I would solve it.

Number of combinations$=\binom{12}2= 66$

Number of combinations in which both are $red=\binom{8}{2}=28$

Probability of choosing 2 two reds= $\frac{28}{66}=\frac{14}{33}$